# Is my gecko's lethargic behaviour due to a heating issue or something else?

Tags: leopard-geckos, temperature, enclosure, heaters

I just got a 5 year-old leopard-gecko from a family friend and I don't think her enclosure is warm enough. It usually reads between 80-85°F and my house is normally around 72°F. I use both a heat pad 24/7 and a heat lamp 12 hours a day.

I'm not sure how much the past owner heated the enclosure, but I'm using the same materials he did so I'm sure she is fine. I'm not sure if she is okay with this 80-85°F heat so I want her enclosure to be at least 90°F.

I read online sometimes leopard-geckos are less active if it’s not warm enough in their enclosure and she sleeps a lot. I'm not sure if this is heat related or just because she’s still shy and not used to me.

Comment: Are you able to post a photo of your setup?